What does a CC BY-NC-SA license imply for neural network weights?
What uses does the CC BY-NC-SA license prohibit in the case of neural network weights?
The license was not written with neural networks in mind, and the non-commercial use is defined with respect to the material (i.e., the weights) itself, not the outputs.
The relevant restrictions are:

   1. Subject to the terms and conditions of this Public License,
     the Licensor hereby grants You a worldwide, royalty-free,
     non-sublicensable, non-exclusive, irrevocable license to
     exercise the Licensed Rights in the Licensed Material to:

       a. reproduce and Share the Licensed Material, in whole or
          in part, for NonCommercial purposes only; and

       b. produce, reproduce, and Share Adapted Material for
          NonCommercial purposes only.


Does the license restrict commercial use, e.g. on generation sites, as long as the model itself is not sold?
Note: Copyright may possibly not apply to neural network weights at all, but since companies releasing weights currently include licenses, the question is how to interpret the license in case the model is copyrighted.

Yes and no. There are several sources of ambiguity here.
A major issue with CC licenses as applied to software this previous question covers some cases where that causes ambiguity. Copyright law generally provides copyright owners with the exclusive right to reproduce (i.e., make copies of) copyrightable works, and a commercial generation site would likely run into issues with that if they were copying some software application, whereas a noncommercial site would be fine, but given use of CC licenses for software is rare, it is unlikely that this has been tested.
But, even worse, it's not clear that ML models are even copyrightable in the first place. To qualify for copyright protection, the work has to be a creative work, and while this is generally accepted for software applications, it is not clear that the process of training a model from data has enough freedom for copyright to apply (Margoni, 2019) or whether an authorship claim could be articulated (Otero, 2021). On the other hand, the EU recognises a sui generis protection similar to (but distinct from) copyright for database rights, even without the creative aspect, which pretrained models could be legally closer to (Otero, 2021). This is not the case in most jurisdictions, for example, US copyright law, including the copyright clause of the constitution (Article I, § 8, cl. 8) has been held to require a minimal degree of creativity (see for example Feist v. Rural), which, again, it is not clear whether pretrained ML models would meet or not.
The gist of it is, given that there is virtually no case law, nobody really knows what the law is. If models are covered under copyright, then by default all rights are exclusive to the author of the work unless it is waived, and the CC BY-NC-SA only waives rights for noncommercial reuse (with some ambiguity for software) so the answer would most likely be yes. However, models might not be covered by copyright law, in which case, the question becomes whether there is other law providing equivalent protection.
Nobody will have a firm answer until someone sues someone else for it, and there are no current lawsuits about the use of the models themselves, as far as I'm aware, so this is unlikely to be resolved anytime soon.

Thanks for your answer. I am aware that there may be no copyright on models, but the companies that add licenses act as if there were (or will be in the future), so my question is about the case when copyright would apply.

timuzhti, welcome to OS.SE, and thanks for a great first answer.  I hope you stay around and write many more such.  +1 from me!
